# How to configure profiling for sentry?

Tags: spring-boot, sentry

I need to read a different properties for Sentry.io in spring boot application based on environment profile (DEV, QA or PROD).

so using next properties for sentry in each bootstrap profile with different values

```
sentry:
  enabled: true
  environment: LOCAL
  servername: localhost
  dsn: MY_DNS_URL
  stacktrace.app.packages:
    - MY_PACKAGE
  sample:
   rate: 0.75
```

So how can i achieve that ??

Comment: This is not a Sentry-related problem. You can just create multiple property files for each environment (application-dev.yml, application-qa.yml, application-prod.yml) with different configurations. And just pass the profile as an environment variable during startup.